# How to generate expiring URL?

Tags: plugins, links

I have a custom post type `Portfolio` and each portfolio is a questionnaire. If I email the link of a portfolio to a client via email.

How can I expire link after 10 minutes, So if client has came after 10 minutes to visit the link Then there should be message that link has expired Please try again.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I came up with this

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_create_questionnaire_link');
function my_create_questionnaire_link(){

  // this check is for demo, if you go to http://yoursite.demo/?create-my-link, you will get your unique url added to your content
  if( isset( $_GET['create-my-link'] ) ){

    // This filter is for demo purpose
    // You might want to create a button or a special page to generate your
    // unique URL
    add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ){

      // This is the relevant part
      // This code will create a unique link containing valid period and a nonce

      $valid_period = 60 * 10; // 10 minutes
      $expiry = current_time( 'timestamp', 1 ) + $valid_period; // current_time( 'timestamp' ) for your blog local timestamp
      $url = site_url( '/path/to/your/portfolio/page' );
      $url = add_query_arg( 'valid', $expiry, $url ); // Adding the timestamp to the url with the "valid" arg
      $nonce_url = wp_nonce_url( $url, 'questionnaire_link_uid_' . $expiry, 'questionnaire' );  // Adding our nonce to the url with a unique id made from the expiry timestamp

      // End of relevant part
      // now here I return my nounce to the content of the post for demo purposed
      // You would use this code when a button is pressed or when a special page is visited

      $content .= $nonce_url;

      return $content;
    } );
  }

}
```

This is where you would check for the validity of the unique URL

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_url_check' );
function my_url_check(){

  if( isset( $_GET['questionnaire'] )){

    // if the nonce fails, redirect to homepage
    if( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['questionnaire'], 'questionnaire_link_uid_' . $_GET['valid'] ) ){
      wp_safe_redirect( site_url() );
      exit;
  }

    // if timestamp is not valid, redirect to homepage
    if( $_GET['valid'] < current_time( 'timestamp', 1) ){
      wp_safe_redirect( site_url() );
      exit;
    }

    // Show your content as normal if all verification passes.
  }
}
```

Comment: In the last code there should be additional } at the end.
$url = site_url - can it be a regular url like http://example.com/my-page
The creation of the link is working fine, but when I try to use it, it always redirects me to home page.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the missing `}`, typo is fixed. For the url, sure it can be whatever url you want, within your site, I've put `site_url` as an example  because it will generate the _mysite.com_ part automatically and is portable to other installs (it takes the url in your WP config) as for the home page redirect, this means one of the 2 checks are failing.  I'm checking for the `$_GET` variable and if you change any of those variable keys, then you need to update the variable names in the check too

Comment: Thanks, I found out that the nonce fails. I haven't change the keys.

Comment: Well I just tested again by pasting the code in my answer and it works perfectly for me... to pass nonce verification,  the parameters have to be identical as when the nonce was created.  so make sure you don't have a typo in your functions and in variable names. match corresponding parameters in `wp_verify_nonce` to `wp_nonce_url`

Comment: I found the error - when I generate the link and open it in new tab in the same browser it works great. But if I open the link in incognito windows or another browser it breaks and redirects to homepage.

Comment: Your issue doesn't make sense and I don't think you found the error. The checks we perform are based on a unique number generated from **A** the url, **B** the timestamp and **C** a unique identifier for that particular action (which is created from the timestamp). The nonce check will fail if the `wp_verify_nonce` function is not able to recreate the same nonce given the parameters we supply to that function, so then you will get redirected (here is where I assumed you had the issue). The other reason you will get redirected is if the timestamp is over the validity period.

Comment: Now it's hard for me to debug without looking at your setup, but I would suggest you try my posted coded into a clean WP default theme (twentysixteen or twentyfifteen ) if it still fails, try disabling all plugins. I cannot help you further as the code above works and I cannot see how the behaviour you are experiencing is related to the code I have posted.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an [custom query var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) with the timestamp.

```
eg. example.com/portfolio?exp=12345678
```

Then, when a user lands on that url, you could check the current time against the timestamp.
If 10 mins have passed / or not, will allow you to output different things on the page.

You could even store a certain timestamp, to know what client got which form/timestamp.

**UPDATE**

As **bynicolas** has noted, technically the client could generate a current time timestamp and access the link again.

So you might want to consider saving that timestamp as a transient, for 10 min.

Now, when the client visits the url, you need to check if that transient with the timestamp [has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435364/check-if-transient-exists-without-retrieving-the-whole-data-in-wordpress).

Just an idea.

Comment: This would work, but then anyone could change the timestamp and gain access to the link again... So the expiration wont be really effective

Comment: You think a client would know how to generate a timestamp? :) But yes that's a possibility. So maybe he could use a 10 min transient with the timestamp. If transient [has expired](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12554255/696481), no access.

Comment: That would make it a nice upgrade, a more robust solution.  I was thinking to integrate a nonce into this.

Comment: That is also a great way to go about it, that's pretty much what they are there for. Just wondering if he's ok with a long url? If yes, then it would be a great solution too. I don't think the transient is necessary at that point, so url "prettiness" and lenght is probably the only thing that matters at this point.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter if the link is long and ugly :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea:  Hook to the `template_redirect` action:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect

At this point, you can examine the $post object to make sure it has the type of your CPT (`$post->post_type`), and get the timestamp (`$post->post_date`).  If the current system time is > 10 minutes beyond the post time, then redirect the user to your desired URL.

You'll probably want to do some sort of "garbage collection" on expired CPTs as well - delete those expired posts so your database doesn't fill up with unneeded content.

Comment: hmm, but then I will need to create new post each time I want to send the link of the post to a client.

Comment: ah.  I read your original question as meaning there *was* a distinct CPT post for each client.  If that's not the case then the answer from The J is better -- and if you are worried about the client deciphering the timestamp being passed in as part of query string - just munge it.  With either symmetric encryption or something quick/easy like convert to base_64.